# SASS Invalid CSS Error: Not Closing Last Style Rule

Tags: sass, compiler-errors

I'm new to SASS and converted a CSS file just to get a base start for my new website. I used this Sublime package, CSS To SASS And Stylus Convert, to convert the CSS to start: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSS%20To%20SASS%20And%20Stylus%20Converter

After converting the old CSS to SASS, I fixed most of the issues after converting. But, I continue to get the following error on the last line couple of lines of code:

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "...ottom: 1.3em; }": expected "}", was ""
```

I'm unsure of why this error is occurring, looking on different questions or other forums with no solution. Also, I tried changing the filetype to .scss with a different error in the syntax occurring.

Could someone help me figure out why the error is occurring and how to correct this?

Below is the SASS I'm currently trying to run. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```css
html, body
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Helvetica, Arial, serif
    font-size: 1em
    font-weight: 400
    line-height: 1.45em

header ul, .mobileMenu
    line-height: 6em
    margin: 0
    padding: 0

.white
    #content
        padding-top: 120px
    header
        background-color: #FFF
        border-bottom: 1px solid #BBBDBF
        #circle
            fill: #6095BF
        #name
            display: none
        .socialLinks
            li
                a[href*="twitter"]
                    background-image: url('../images/twitter.png')
                a[href*="linkedin"]
                    background-image: url('../images/linkedin.png')
                a[href*="pinterest"]
                    background-image: url('../images/pinterest.png')
        #symbol
            fill: #F1F1F2
        a
            color: #6094BE
            &.active
                color: #000

.mobileMenu
    display: inline-block
    line-height: 5.65em
    position: absolute
    right: 20px

h1, h2, h3, h4
    font-family: "Ashbury Light"
    line-height: 1.2em
    margin: 1.414em 0 0.5em

footer
    background-color: #6094BE
    color: #FFF
    padding: 25px 20px 50px 120px
    padding: 25px 20px
    div
        display: inline-block
        width: 33%
        width: 36%
    a
        color: #FFF

#pgImg
    background-color: #6094BE
    color: #FFF
    height: 465px
    position: relative
    h1
        left: 120px
        position: absolute
        top: 250px
        left: 0

nav
    width: initial
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BBBDBF
    display: none
    margin-right: 0
    &.active
        display: block
        position: static
        width: 100%
    li
        border-top: 1px solid #BBBDBF
        display: block
        line-height: 3em
        text-align: center
    a
        margin-right: 15px
        display: list-item
        margin: 0

nav, .socialLinks
    display: inline-block
    float: right
    position: relative

small
    font-size: 0.75em

@font-face
    font-family: 'Ashbury Light'
    src: url('../fonts/2D395B_0_0.eot')
    src: url('../fonts/2D395B_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/2D395B_0_0.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/2D395B_0_0.ttf') format('truetype')
    font-style: normal
    font-weight: normal
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro'
    src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.eot')
    src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.svg#f59ec01e9ce984a5e7320939532a55f3') format('svg')
    font-style: normal
    font-weight: 400
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro Bold'
    src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.eot')
    src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf')  format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.svg#f59ec01e9ce984a5e7320939532a55f3') format('svg')
    font-style: normal
    font-weight: 700

.socialLinks
    margin-right: 20px
    display: none
    li
        a
            background-position: center
            background-repeat: no-repeat
            height: 25px
            display: inline-block
            margin-left: 10px
            text-indent: -9999px
            vertical-align: middle
            width: 30px

header a, .mobileMenu
    color: #FFF
    text-decoration: none
    text-transform: uppercase

nav li, .socialLinks li
    display: inline-block
    list-style-type: none

h1, h2, h3, h4, p
    padding: 0 20px

.home
    display: list-item


    @media screen and (max-width: 660px)
        .white #content { padding-top: 91px

a
    color: #6095BF

h3
    font-size: 1.777em

#content
    padding: 0 25px 25px 120px
    padding: 0

@media screen and (min-width : 660px)
    .mobileMenu, .home { display: none

h4
    font-size: 1.333em

h1
    font-size: 3.157em
    margin-top: 10px

h2
    font-size: 2.369em

header
    background-color: #6094BE
    position: fixed
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out
    width: 100%
    z-index: 5
    .logo
        height: 100px
        margin-left: 20px
        vertical-align: middle
        width: 300px
        height: 90px
        width: 250px
    #name
        path
            fill: #F1F1F2
    .socialLinks
        li
            a[href*="twitter"]
                background-image: url('../images/twitter-white.png')
            a[href*="linkedin"]
                background-image: url('../images/linkedin-white.png')
            a[href*="pinterest"]
                background-image: url('../images/pinterest-white.png')
    #circle
        fill: #F1F1F2
    #symbol
        fill: #6095BF

p
    margin-bottom: 1.3em
```

Comment: as my suggestion you should use gulp/grunt so you can do much more with the compilers. Like vendor prefix, compress, concat and much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're error was due to to a couple of bad indentations, and you also have a few stray opening curly braces (SCSS syntax lines 154 and 167) where it should have been a new line (SASS syntax).

**For instance:**

```
.mobileMenu, .home { display: none
```

**Should be:**

```
.mobileMenu, .home
    display: none
```

**A corrected and compiled file can be seen here:**

https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/425717147defa3298e9d01036155cbfc

**And corrected source:**

```
html, body
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, Arial, serif
  font-size: 1em
  font-weight: 400
  line-height: 1.45em
header ul, .mobileMenu
  line-height: 6em
  margin: 0
  padding: 0
.white
  #content
    padding-top: 120px
  header
    background-color: #FFF
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BBBDBF
    #circle
      fill: #6095BF
    #name
      display: none
    .socialLinks
      li
        a[href*="twitter"]
          background-image: url('../images/twitter.png')
        a[href*="linkedin"]
          background-image: url('../images/linkedin.png')
        a[href*="pinterest"]
          background-image: url('../images/pinterest.png')
    #symbol
      fill: #F1F1F2
    a
      color: #6094BE
      &.active
        color: #000
.mobileMenu
  display: inline-block
  line-height: 5.65em
  position: absolute
  right: 20px
h1, h2, h3, h4
  font-family: "Ashbury Light"
  line-height: 1.2em
  margin: 1.414em 0 0.5em
footer
  background-color: #6094BE
  color: #FFF
  padding: 25px 20px 50px 120px
  padding: 25px 20px
  div
    display: inline-block
    width: 33%
    width: 36%
  a
    color: #FFF
#pgImg
  background-color: #6094BE
  color: #FFF
  height: 465px
  position: relative
  h1
    left: 120px
    position: absolute
    top: 250px
    left: 0
nav
  width: initial
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBBDBF
  display: none
  margin-right: 0
  &.active
    display: block
    position: static
    width: 100%
  li
    border-top: 1px solid #BBBDBF
    display: block
    line-height: 3em
    text-align: center
  a
    margin-right: 15px
    display: list-item
    margin: 0
nav, .socialLinks
  display: inline-block
  float: right
  position: relative
small
  font-size: 0.75em
@font-face
  font-family: 'Ashbury Light'
  src: url('../fonts/2D395B_0_0.eot'),
  src: url('../fonts/2D395B_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')
  url('../fonts/2D395B_0_0.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/2D395B_0_0.ttf') format('truetype'),
  font-style: normal
  font-weight: normal
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro'
  src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.eot'),
  src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')
  url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.svg#f59ec01e9ce984a5e7320939532a55f3') format('svg'),
  font-style: normal
  font-weight: 400
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro Bold'
  src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.eot'),
  src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')
  url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf')  format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.svg#f59ec01e9ce984a5e7320939532a55f3') format('svg'),
  font-style: normal
  font-weight: 700
.socialLinks
  margin-right: 20px
  display: none
  li
    a
      background-position: center
      background-repeat: no-repeat
      height: 25px
      display: inline-block
      margin-left: 10px
      text-indent: -9999px
      vertical-align: middle
      width: 30px
header a, .mobileMenu
  color: #FFF
  text-decoration: none
  text-transform: uppercase
nav li, .socialLinks li
  display: inline-block
  list-style-type: none
h1, h2, h3, h4, p
  padding: 0 20px
.home
  display: list-item
  @media screen and (max-width: 660px)
    .white #content 
      padding-top: 91px
a
  color: #6095BF
h3
  font-size: 1.777em
#content
  padding: 0 25px 25px 120px
  padding: 0
@media screen and (min-width : 660px)
  .mobileMenu, .home 
    display: none
h4
  font-size: 1.333em
h1
  font-size: 3.157em
  margin-top: 10px
h2
  font-size: 2.369em
header
  background-color: #6094BE
  position: fixed
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out
  width: 100%
  z-index: 5
  .logo
    height: 100px
    margin-left: 20px
    vertical-align: middle
    width: 300px
    height: 90px
    width: 250px
  #name
    path
      fill: #F1F1F2
  .socialLinks
    li
      a[href*="twitter"]
        background-image: url('../images/twitter-white.png')
      a[href*="linkedin"]
        background-image: url('../images/linkedin-white.png')
      a[href*="pinterest"]
        background-image: url('../images/pinterest-white.png')
  #circle
    fill: #F1F1F2
  #symbol
    fill: #6095BF
p
  margin-bottom: 1.3em
```

Comment: I didn't see both of those brackets! I should've looked more carefully. Thank you so much!